# code gets executed before the specified setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code:I expect line of code to be executed after specified time period, but it executes them before the timeout.

How can I ensure they wait for the specified amount of time before execute it?

```
var timeout;
       $('body').on('input', '.set_price', function() {
         if(timeout) {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = null;
        }
        var dInput = this.value;
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

         timeout = setTimeout(2000)
        //after 2sec starts
        $(this).attr("data-price",dInput);
        shoppingCart.setPriceForItem(dInput,id);
        displayCart();
        //after 2sec ends
        });
```

I tried making callback on timeout like this to no avail:

```
 timeout = setTimeout(2000,funciton(){
            //after 2sec starts
            $(this).attr("data-price",dInput);
            shoppingCart.setPriceForItem(dInput,id);
            displayCart();
            //after 2sec ends
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct profile for `setTimeout` is `setTimeout(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)`. In your code you put the milliseconds before the function. Try this:

```
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    //after 2sec starts
    $(this).attr("data-price",dInput);
    shoppingCart.setPriceForItem(dInput,id);
    displayCart();
    //after 2sec ends
}, 2000);
```

Comment: [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

The setTimeout() function has the following form

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

your code:

```
 timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            //after 2sec starts
            $(this).attr("data-price",dInput);
            shoppingCart.setPriceForItem(dInput,id);
            displayCart();
            //after 2sec ends
},2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
  $(this).attr("data-price",dInput);
   shoppingCart.setPriceForItem(dInput,id);
   setTimeout(function(){ displayCart(); }, 2000);
```